# Find weighted characteristics for each row of 2 matrices using apply() function in R

Tags: r, apply

I have 2 matrices and I want to use `apply()` to apply weighted median,weighted iqr and weighted quantiles for each row.I want something like:

```
apply(z, 1, function(x) weighted.mean(x[1:3], x[4:6]))

w<- matrix(c(3, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 1, 2, 0,
           1, 0, 1, 1,
           0, 3, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 2, 1,
           1, 0, 1, 1), nrow = 6, ncol = 6)


x<- matrix(c(-1.569192, 0.0000000, 0, 0.0000000,
             0.000000, -0.6744898, 0, 0.0000000,
             0.000000, 0.0000000, 0, 0.0000000,
             0.000000, 0.0000000, 0, 0.6744898,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), nrow = 6, ncol = 6)
```

Comment: median, iqr, and quantiles depend on the proportion of data above or below certain points so I'm not certain it makes sense to weight them.

Comment: these are the 2 matrices I have. Can this be done?

Comment: Can be done like this `means=c()
for (i in 1:nrow(w)) {
  means=c(means, weighted.mean(x[i,], w[i,]))
}` but probably not with `apply`

Comment: I have to use apply() to do it.

Comment: This works `apply(cbind(x, w), 1, function(x) {weighted.mean(x[1:6], x[7:12])})` if you mean to weight each row of x by the same index row of w as weights. Was that the intention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take the weighted mean of each row of x using the row of w having the same index as weights, you can do `apply(cbind(x, w), 1, function(x) {weighted.mean(x[1:6], x[7:12])})`.

Comment: if you would like to create a function for it how would you do it??

Comment: Very easy, just wrap it in a function call, unless I'm misunderstanding. `my_func=function(mat, weights) {
  return(apply(cbind(mat, weights), 1, function(x) {weighted.mean(x[1:6], x[7:12])}))
}
my_func(x, w)`